# how to get positions of non empty values in a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Here is my dictionary:

```
d={"1":"", "2":"", "3":"", "4":"rock" , "5":"" , "6":"" ,"7":"paper","8":""}
```

I want the position of keys and values for which values are non empty.
i tried with:

```
d.items()
```

Output :

```
[('1', ''), ('3', ''), ('2', ''), ('5', ''), ('4', 'rock'), ('7', 'paper'), ('6', ''), ('8', '')]
```

I want my output to be :

```
4 rock
7 paper
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this?

```
d={"1":"", "2":"", "3":"", "4":"rock" , "5":"" , "6":"" ,"7":"paper","8":""}

for key, value in d.items():
    if value:
        print(key, value)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> d = {"1":"", "2":"", "3":"", "4":"rock" , "5":"" , "6":"" ,"7":"paper","8":""}
>>> print {k: v for k, v in d.items() if v}
{'7': 'paper', '4': 'rock'}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
from __future__ import print_function

data = {
    '1': '', '2': '', '3': '', '4': 'rock',
    '5': '', '6': '', '7': 'paper', '8': '',
    }

new_data = {k: v for k, v in data.items() if v}

for k, v in new_data.items():
    print(k, v)
```